# Sens de l'expression « à l'armée »

Tags: expressions, sens, prépositions

J'ai un petit problème pour comprendre (et traduire) une expression. Il s'agit de *à l'armée*.
Il n'y a presque aucun contexte sauf que c'est une lettre écrite: "le 4 février 1940 (à l'armée)". Je sais que l'auteur de la lettre a participé à la Seconde Guerre mondiale. Cela veut-il donc dire *in the army*? Je pensais que ce serait *dans l'armée* et j'ai besoin de comprendre le sens exact.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

On emploie parfois *à l'armée* pour signifier *en tant que soldat*, *en tant que membre du régiment* :

> *En 1992, j'étais à l'armée. Je ne travaille dans le civil que depuis 93.* (à cette période la personne effectuait son service militaire ou s'était engagée)

Concernant cette lettre, "*le 4 février 1940 (à l'armée)*" signifie que la personne était appelée ou s'était enrôlée en tant que soldat. Elle écrivait vraisemblablement du front, de la caserne, ou de tout autre endroit où l'armée exigeait qu'elle se trouve.

Comment: Le sens me semble bien évident maintenant. Merci beaucoup!

Answer (score 4):

Je pense que l'expression "à l'armée" pourrait être traduite différemment par "à l'époque ou j'étais dans l'armée".

Pour moi, dans ce contexte, cela sert à souligner qu'à cette date là, l'auteur faisait partie des forces armées, mais que ce n'est plus le cas depuis.

Answer (score 4):

Dans les courriers officiels, on précise le lieu où a été écrit la lettre, à coté de la date. Par exemple :

> Le 17/07/2013, à Paris

Cela peut expliquer l'expression "à l'armée" plutôt que "dans l'armée", pour reprendre la formule consacrée.